# How should we deal with questions asking about what hardware to use for something?

Tags: discussion, questions

[This question](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/463/155) was just asked. The OP is asking about how to achieve something and needs a recommendation of what hardware to use in the first place rather than a recommendation of a certain product.

Firstly, at the time of writing this, the question doesn't have much to work with, so it should be closed as too broad. However, if the OP were to add more info about what needs to be done, budget, ideal specs, etc., I want to say this could possibly pass as on-topic.

Secondly, the question seems to be asking about a sort of DIY situation which isn't on-topic but at the same time asks about what to use. Kinda tricky.

So should questions like this be allowed through (keeping in mind that they, of course, still need detail)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written, I think the question is broad.

The user has not provided much more to go on than a case brand and a vague reference to LinusTechTips. If I were to guess, I'd guess Linus Torvalds, but "tech tips" doesn't seem to be what he's know for.

"Can someone recommend a way to achieve this?" is not a product recommendation question. It does not feel like this question falls into the ["pre-purchase inquiries"](https://hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139/is-a-scope-of-product-recommendations-pre-purchase-inquiries-agreeable) either. It feels more like a "I saw this cool thing, how do I make that, but better?" question.

The question *does* mention LED lighting and power supplies, but doesn't provide any more details than that. I believe the user needs to do some more research and return when they can provide more details and then we can provide recommendations for lighting or power to the computer case.

Comment: What I got from reading it was that the OP needs a recommendation of what to use to achieve his goal, but I guess that's exactly why it's broad: I read it differently than you did.

Comment: I meant LinusTechTips as the YouTube channel, not Linus Torvalds.