# Requesting product recommendation and/or information leading to product decision

Tags: discussion, questions

The Help Center guidelines say a question can request a product recommendation or information that will lead to a product decision. Just want to confirm whether a question will be on-topic (or frame it so that it is).

I'm looking for a webcam and have operational requirements. Researching models raises questions about the various specs and options, and how they relate to my operational requirements (I need to do ABC, webcams come with features X or Y; which feature is needed for ABC?).

I'm happy to just post operational requirements and get specific product recommendations, but it would be good to understand the feature choices behind the recommendations. If someone doesn't have a good specific recommendation but can clarify the feature choices needed for my operational requirements, I can intelligently research specific models on my own. Or, if someone has settled on a compromise in features but it is adequate for their needs, understanding the choices would allow me to assess suitability for my own requirements.

Can my question include both the operation requirements and the unclear feature choices, where answers could be either a specific product or clarification of the appropriate feature choices to meet the requirements? Or should it be one or the other?

Just to add a complication, one of the listed similar questions suggested while writing this is [Not Every Question Will Have a Product Recommendation](https://hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/574/not-every-question-will-have-a-product-recommendation). That's over 6 years old, so policies could have changed. But the gist of that thread is that only product recommendations are on-topic (suggests that information leading to a product decision either isn't on-topic, or fits only very specific cases).