# I do not understand why this post is off-topic:

Tags: bug, deleted-questions

I have a question about my Hardware Recommendations Stack Exchange post: [Need recommendations for a router for use with network cameras](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/12362/need-recommendations-for-a-router-for-use-with-network-cameras)

My post was deleted (now on hold) as off-topic. Could someone explain why?  The forum is called “Hardware Recommendations” and I’m looking for a specific hardware recommendation.  I saw the explanation:

“posts should detail why a simple product search did not work for you. Unfortunately the "requirements" listed are not sufficient to narrow down the possible solutions in any definitive way.”

I have now edited the post to give more requirements and explain why a simple product search is insufficient for the specific question I have (suitability for multiple wifi cameras, not gaming). If this is still not satisfactory, please someone explain why.  Also, there is a problem in that if a post is deleted, the system won't let the user revise it by following the edit post link.

Answer (score 1):

Your post is now much closer to being on-topic than it was in its first iteration. There are two issues remaining that are currently stopping it being reopened.

1. **[We do recommendations, not advice.](https://hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/343/do-we-still-want-general-advice-questions)**
   Asking for advice about what *kind* of hardware, or *what to look for* in hardware when buying, or equivalents, is off-topic. Your post is asking for this: last paragraph:

   > I am looking for either: advice on what aspect of the specifications to look for, or, specific recommendations for a brand and model that is known to handle network camera streams without dropping connectivity.

   The first half of this sentence (and the related previous sentence)  is off-topic.
2. **There's not quite enough information**

   - You've already included that you're looking to support 20 concurrent connections; that's useful. How intermittent (or not) are these connections? I imagine the cameras are almost constant-on; the desktop and mobile devices are currently unknown.
   - How much are you willing to spend on this purchase?
   - What else does the hardware need to support? Do you need *any* Ethernet connections? Do you need a particular range? Are you willing to consider a router + range extenders, if that's easier/cheaper?

If you can edit your post to address those points, we should be able to reopen it.

Comment: thank you; I have edited the post to hopefully cover all of the specific points you indicated.