# Closure of pre-purchase question?

Tags: discussion

https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/13559/best-way-to-use-multiple-cpus-to-perform-independent-tasks had the OP asking how to select hardware for multiple simultaneous processes. They had not bought anything yet, and were seeking pre-purchase recommendations to perform a particular task.

I'm baffled as to its deletion. Perhaps you could illuminate this for me, in particular what would be required to lead to undeletion?

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from the help center (/help/on-topic):

> #### Questions asking for information that will lead to a product decision
>
> Please be aware this is a fine line to walk. While these questions are on-topic here, ["general advice" type questions are *not*](https://hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/343/do-we-still-want-general-advice-questions), and will be closed. That means that asking about characteristics of a limited set of hardware options *is* okay, but asking more generally "how do I choose X hardware" is not.

That question was pretty clearly asking the latter: "How do I go about doing this?" and "Would it be best to..." aren't asking about the characteristics of a limited set of hardware options.

Comment: Thank you for the response.