# Discussion about closed question

Tags: discussion

Posted a question about CPU upgrade options in Super User, but mods said it is more appropriate to this forum. So I asked to migrate the [question](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/6841/5598).

Checking a short while later, I see it is already put on hold, saying it is too broad. As a newcomer to this site, I may misunderstand its intention.

How can [this question](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/1784/motherboard-and-cpu-what-and-how-to-choose?rq=1) be more on-topic and more specific than mine?

Answer (score 2):

At the time the [first question](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/1784/motherboard-and-cpu-what-and-how-to-choose?rq=1) was asked, the community was debating on whether or not these types of "What should I consider..." questions should be allowed. See these two questions:

- [Are "What should I consider when buying" questions allowed?](https://hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4/are-what-should-i-consider-when-buying-questions-allowed)
- [Do we still want general advice questions?](https://hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/343/do-we-still-want-general-advice-questions)

It's fair to note that I [reviewed](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/1375) the question from the review queue and said it should be open at the time.

The [final decision](https://hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/345/57) to not allow these wasn't made until March of 2016, at which point they were not allowed. When this decision was made, the question you are asking about was not closed. That has since been fixed (due to this meta question).

---

Your specific question seems to been on the edge of "ok". You have described what you want the new processor to do, but something that is missing is a description of why the two you've identified won't work for you. We don't just provide a list of hardware, our goal is to solve a specific problem you are having, and a description of why those two don't work would help greatly.

Comment: "which offer a very minor improvement." - isn't this a good enough reason why the two mentioned won't work for me?

Comment: "goal is to solve a specific problem" - maybe it's just me, but I did not get the sense of this from reading the FAQ.

Comment: @ysap This answer is pretty much spot on. For context, I closed the question because pretty much the only criterion I could identify for the new processor was "fits this socket", which kinda isn't enough information to narrow the field down significantly.

Comment: Well, I guess I'll have to accept and live with that, and maybe find another online forum for my particular question.

Comment: @yasp Your other option could be to narrow down your criteria, at which point it may be reopened.